# Trouble with running both Percy and Cypress with Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, cypress, percy

[image: I am able to run Cypress in Bitbucket but when I give percy exec -- cypress command then it gives this error.]

[image: Here is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml sample. Not sure how to initialize percy.]

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What if you run `npm ci` in the test step? It might not properly cache the needed dependencies

Comment: Also, do read how to use secrets in your pipeline so you don't have to poorly hide them https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/